# Rotating a view in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, rotation

I have a UIView in my view. Right now I have a button moving the UIView on it's y axis.  Here is my code

```
CGRect frame2 = self.test22.frame;
    frame2.origin.y -= 1.f/[UIScreen mainScreen].scale;  //however many pixels to the right..
    self.test22.frame = frame2;
```

But how can I rotate it?  Except using the x or y axis. I want to be able to move the UIView by rotation by 1.f.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to SO. You want to look at the UIView method animateWithDuration, and the view's transform property. You'd apply a rotation transform to the view in your animation block. Note that if you change a view's transform, you should not read or write the frame property. Instead use the center property to change the position and the bounds.size property if you need to change the size.

Your code might look like this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration: .25
  animations: ^
  {
    self.test22.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
    CGPoint center = self.test22.center;
    center.y -= 1;
    self.test22.center = center;
  }
];
```

### EDIT:

I have no idea what you mean when you say "I want to be able to move the UIView by rotation by 1.f." Rotating a view is not moving it, it's rotating it. And rotation is expressed as an angle, not a value like "1". Furthermore, the angle is in radians, where π is 180 degrees, π/2 is 90 degrees, and 2π is a full-circle rotation (or no change, since it puts the rotation back at it's original value.) You have to think in terms of fractions of 2π when you do rotations. Or you can use degrees and convert to radians, where:

```
degrees = radians * 180/π
```

Also, your code that moves the view will only change the view's position by half a point on retina displays which doesn't make much sense.

Comment: That code works.  But when i want to move the objects again after i rotated them, they disappear. Why is that?

Comment: As I said in my answer, don't try to manipulate the frame property on a view where you have set the transform property to anything other than the identity transform (not changed). If you do it doesn't work, and strange things can happen. Is that what you are doing?

Comment: I'm guessing that is what i'm doing. Like in my question.  I'm just using that code to move the object up and down.  Then using the code you gave, for rotation.  After rotating it, if i try to rotate it again it disappears.

Comment: Remove all code that changes the view's frame if you are also doing rotation or other changes to the view's transform. Change your movement code to change the view's center property instead.

Answer (score 0):

To Rotate the UIView create the object of UIView (*view) and make transform on it

Lets to rotate the view 90 degree use below code

CGAffineTransform r_transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity;

r_transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(r_transform,DegreeYoRadians(90));

view.transform = r_transform;